# Pull requests merged manually after a rebase don't show as merged on Github

Tags: git, github, merge, command-line-interface, rebase

In order to keep a linear history, I use the following approach to merge changes instead of relying on github's merge functionality:

```
git checkout -b feature_x user/feature_x
git rebase master                           
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature_x
git push origin master                       # On Github: PR gets merged and closed
git branch -D feature_x
```

The above works perfectly fine but in cases when I have to manually resolve conflicts, the PR doesn't show up as merged on Github automatically and I have to manually close the PR.

Is there a better approach to merging the pull requests that automatically shows Github PRs merged and closed?

Comment: i think it's the rebase, and not the conflicts, that cause github to be unable to identify that the pull request was merged.

Comment: @Gordon You are right. Rebasing a branch creates a different set of commits which has nothing to do with the original set of commits and github is unable to detect that the new commits are related to the same pull request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [onlythefinestwilldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2722512/onlythefinestwilldo) has rightly pointed out, once a branch is rebased, it contains a different set of commits which means that the original pull request will not be affected.

To overcome this problem, we have changed our process: now, we **do not rebase branch when merging the changes to master**. If the changes can't be merged, the creator of the pull request is asked to rebase their branch and update the pull request. Though inconvenient, this is the only way to make sure that the pull requests automatically get closed when merged.

Answer (score 1):

Since the feature is rebased, its commit history is totally offset.  It is basically a new branch at that point.

You could force push the rebased feature branch, overwriting the pull request (assuming you're the maintainer and you have write access to forks).

`$ git push -f [feature] [remote] [feature]`

Once GitHub gets the new master, the pull request will be closed.

Comment: Like you said, this requires write access to forks which is a different scenario. Also, it is fine to change the local history but it is not recommended to change the public history, specially when it can affect another user, which will be the creator of the pull request in this case.